# To restrict menu tab using Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to restrict a menu tab if you aren't loggin previously and therefore to redirect to the loggin web page.

For example, if I have in the layout/main.php:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Visit us', 'url'=>array('/visit/index')),
            array('label'=>'Employee', 'url'=>array('/employee/index')),
            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
```

and I want to restrict the menu tab Employee what and where I should to write the restriction?

I read in another post somethings like this, but I don't know how to use it:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"]))
{
    header("Location: homepage.php");
}
```

PLEASE, somebody could help me? THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly [written in docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu). To define if menu element is visible, simply use `visible` params, same as for login page, but with negation:

```
array('label'=>'Visit us', 'url'=>array('/visit/index')),
array('label'=>'Employee', 'url'=>array('/employee/index'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
```

To control access to employee use [access control filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter)

Comment: Hi PeterM, thank you very much and sorry my question but before created the post I tried using "'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest)", and as you can imagine it didn't works...I forgot the symbol "!"...Now everything works well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get you preperly but i think you dont want to show employee menu link to guest user....

if you are looking for that then you have check condition inside main.php only...

```
 if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest())
 {
     <div id="mainmenu">
      <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
      'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Visit us', 'url'=>array('/visit/index')),
        // array('label'=>'Employee', 'url'=>array('/employee/index')),
        array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest), 
    //your code
 }
 else
 {
  <div id="mainmenu">
      <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
      'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Visit us', 'url'=>array('/visit/index')),
        array('label'=>'Employee', 'url'=>array('/employee/index')),
        array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
        //your code
 }
```

about you said you want to transfer user to login page if he doesn't logged in.... this thing automatically done in yii if you are using yii inbuilt login form

Comment: Hello Kalpit, thanks for helping me, but I was searching something like the answer of PeterM since I think that his solution is better  and easier hehe. Thanks again.